# Securing Spring RESTful webservice APIs from unautherized access?

Tags: android, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have successfully created a Spring RESTful webservice with different APIs. Now I should protect them from unauthorized access. I followed http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html and the login logic is entirely different from mine. Can someone help me to move on?

***Fetch user login request***

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public UserResponse login(@RequestBody final UserLoginRequest userRequest) throws ServletException, IOException {
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        try {
            userResponse = accessService.login(userRequest);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userResponse;
    }
```

***Process user login request***

```
 @Transactional
    public UserResponse login(UserLoginRequest userRequest) throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();

        int status = 0;

        //boolean isExist = loginDao.isUserExist(userRequest.getUsername(), userRequest.getPassword());
        User user = loginDao.getUser(userRequest.getEmailID());
        if (user != null) {
            if (userRequest.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {//Case sensitive password and added to check status
                //User exist
                if (user.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                    //Device token check
                    loginDao.isDeviceTokenExists(userRequest, user.getProfileId());

                    status = 2;
                } else {
                    status = 3;
                }
            } else {
                status = 4;
            }
        } else {
            status = 1;
        }
        if (status == 1) {
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.USER_EMAIL_EXIST_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("User does not exists.Please Register.");
        } else if (status == 2) {
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.SUCCESS_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("User login success");
            userResponse.setId(user.getProfileId());
        } else if (status == 3) {
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("Your Account is blocked. Please contact Weekenter administrator.");
            userResponse.setId(user.getProfileId());
        } else if (status == 4) {
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("Password is wrong.");
            userResponse.setId(user.getProfileId());
        }
        return userResponse;
    }
```

I have API's for fetch countries, userlist etc. Those services should only give data to the Android client once the user is valid. I know the authentication will be processed by using access token. How could I do it in a standard way?

Comment: Well, for securing such an API (login, for example) you need two things:
One, a csrf token - to protect against cross-site request forgery. This is basically a crumb, a random server-generated string that is output as a hidden form field on the login page. When you submit the login form, the server verifies this csrf token to check if it was the same as the one it generated. These are short-lived - about 5 minutes. The other thing you would need is to have a shared secret which is used by the app to acquire a short-lived access token. Access token should be single-use.

Comment: So you register a user. You have their email address (say). User now logs in using your login API and you can generate an access token by encrypting some data and base64 encoding it - e.g. HMAC(email address + users' creation timestamp, shared secret). Read about hmac. It uses a shared symmetric key. You need to share this symmetric key with the user - one way could be by sending them an email with this key once they register.

Comment: Good question.i was surfing for this along.plz any one provide an answer for this.

Comment: @Farhad.I know the authentication will be processed by using access token.and i know the logic too.but how i could do it in a standard way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can follow the mentioned tutorial itself by changing the login
>   logic in your service.define a custom authentication service in your
>   `spring-security.xml`.
>
> Typically, a simple Spring Security enabled application would use a
>   simple user service as the authentication source:

```
<!--Custom User details service which is provide the user data-->
<bean id="customUserDetailsService"
          class="com.yourpackage.CustomUserDetailsService" />

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

> Your `customUserDetailsService` should implement `UserDetailsService`
>   available in
>   `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`

```
import com.weekenter.www.dao.LoginDao;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        com.weekenter.www.entity.User user = null;
        try {
            user = loginDao.getUser(login);//login variable contain your requested username 
            if (user != null) {
                if (user.getStatus().equals("1")) {
                    enabled = false;
                }
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(login + " Not found !");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex1) {
            }
        }

 <!-- Password comparison will happen here -->
        return new User(
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),
                enabled,
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                getAuthorities()
        );
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles());
        return authList;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
        roles.add("ROLE_APP");
        return roles;
    }

    public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (String role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

> And finally in `spring-security.xml` you can filter protected URL's
>   like below

```
<!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
    and what roles have access to them -->
    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
              entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
              access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
              xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="ROLE_APP" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fantastic pease answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a separate process that will authorize a device for use in your application.

I have worked on an application in which tablets are registered for using an app. The tablet ID is saved in a simple text file that is accessible to the Apache server. Then all REST requests have a special header X_DEVICEID which contains the device ID, and a PHP script used by Apache checks for this ID in the file, and will only give a response if the ID is for a registered device.

The file of allowed device IDs acts as a sort of firewall to block unregistered devices.

Comment: Please , Aware that spring security is the standardized way..we have to adopt same..